# Prove general sequence is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $a_n \leq (a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})/2$ and $n\geq 2$. 
How to find that $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with your question. Suppose that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$. Then the condition is satisfied, since $0 \leq (0+0)/2$, but the sequence $0,0,0,\ldots$ is not decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n\le \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}{2}$$
$$\frac{a_n}{2}\le \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}-a_n}{2}$$
$$\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\le \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{2}$$
$$a_n-a_{n-1}\le a_{n+1}-a_n$$
And so if you let $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n,$
$$b_{n-1}\le b_n$$
Which shows that the sequence isn't actually decreasing!

Comment: What if we assume that $a_n \neq 0$ then could we could do:
$a_n/2-a_{n-1}/2 \leq (a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})/2-a_{n-1}/2 then we get
a_n - a_{n-1} \leq a_{n+1}$

From this it appears as if the equation is only satisfied if sequence is decreasing.